# "There is" or "There are": which is appropriate before "a whole slew of academic articles"?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, there-is, quantifiers, premodifiers

> There **are** a whole slew of academic articles.

To me, it seems that this sentence should say "There **is** a whole slew of academic articles," because the agreement should be with "slew." But I'm having a hard time finding which is correct and why after much Googling.

Comment: Since "slew" is colloquial, either is fine.  I'd **say**, "There's a whole slew of academic articles." but would write something more formal, like "There are very many academic articles."

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Oxford dictionary article](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/09/agreement-over-collective-nouns/), both are correct. "Slew" is a *collective noun*, like "team" or "group". And in general:

> [T]he verb form used can depend on the emphasis of the sentence, and accepted regional usage, so no wonder many people are confused. In British English it’s absolutely fine to treat **most** collective nouns as either singular or plural – you can say *my husband's **family is** very religious* or *my husband's **family are** very religious.*
>
> *[...]* in American English you are much more likely to see, for example:
>
> *His company's legal **team is** investigating the matter.*
>
> rather than:
>
> *His company's legal **team are** investigating the matter.*

So both "is" and "are" are acceptable here.

Comment: I'd say this is notional agreement with vague quantifiers rather than notional agreement with collective/group nouns (the latter of which has been done to death here).